# IronSource Banner Ad in Android Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, ads, ironsource

I have found a similar question asked which was answered for AdMob, but has no examples for ironSource or Unity LevelPlay ads.

For AdMob:

```kotlin
AndroidView(
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            factory = { context ->
                AdView(context).apply {
                    adSize = AdSize.BANNER
                    adUnitId = context.getString(R.string.ad_id_banner)
                    loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                }
            }
        )
```

So for the above it looks like you would need a class similar to AdMob `AdView` but I was struggling to get this working with ironSource.

Is it possible to show ironSource ads with Android Jetpack Compose?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Android view* similar to the example you have shared. You just need to `inflate` the Banner Layout and additionally set `levelplay` listeners to this layout, finally load banner by passing the layout.

Example, use the below code in your composable.

```
AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(50.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .background(color = Color.Black),
            factory = {
                IronSource.createBanner(context as Activity?, ISBannerSize.BANNER)
            },
            update = {
                Logger.d(TAG, "Banner layout inflated")
                ADManager.getInstance(context.applicationContext).setBannerLayout(it)
            })
```

And then set the listeners on this layout and load banner.

```
fun setBannerLayout(ironSourceBannerLayout: IronSourceBannerLayout){
   
        bannerLayout = ironSourceBannerLayout
        bannerLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        bannerLayout.levelPlayBannerListener = object : LevelPlayBannerListener {
            override fun onAdLoaded(p0: AdInfo?) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "Banner onAdLoaded")
                bannerLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

            override fun onAdLoadFailed(p0: IronSourceError?) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "Banner onAdLoadFailed")
            }

            override fun onAdClicked(p0: AdInfo?) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "Banner onAdClicked")
            }

            override fun onAdLeftApplication(p0: AdInfo?) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "Banner onAdLeftApplication")
            }

            override fun onAdScreenPresented(p0: AdInfo?) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "Banner onAdScreenPresented")
            }

            override fun onAdScreenDismissed(p0: AdInfo?) {
                Logger.d(TAG, "Banner onAdScreenDismissed")
            }

        }
        Logger.d("banner", "will try to load banner")
        IronSource.loadBanner(bannerLayout)
    
}
```